# Transfer ERC-20 token from Token Contract to My Custom Contract

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I know transferring ERC-20 token from my wallet to a custom contract. The smart contract has to call `transferFrom()` to enable withdraw.

```
ERC20 token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
token.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, _amount);
```

But I need to first call approve function on the token contract to approve this contract to withraw funds on my behalf. I want to know is there any way to call the `token.approve()` method from this contract itself?

Answer (score 1):

`token.approve()` has to be called by the account that owns the tokens (you), so no, you can't call it from some other account (including a contract).